# UITableView select Segue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iOS and I do not understand why when I click on my item in the cell it goes nowhere. No errors, no nothing. My segue ID is Cell. I Have a Button that works fine to add data, but I am trying to get to update the data if selected from the table.

Here is my `.h` and `.m`

DerbyProTableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DerbyProTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *racerarray;
@end
```

DerbyProTableViewController.m:

```
#import "DerbyProTableViewController.h"
#import "DerbyProDetailViewController.h"

@interface DerbyProTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation DerbyProTableViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Racer"];
    self.racerarray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
   return self.racerarray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.racerarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [device valueForKey:@"lastname"], [device valueForKey:@"firstname"]]];
    return cell;

}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.racerarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.racerarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"updateracer"]){
     NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.racerarray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
     DerbyProDetailViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
     destinationViewController.derbyprodb = selectedDevice;
 }

 }
```

Comment: Where is the call `performSegueWithIdentifier`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going on just what I see in the code you pasted. I don't know what might have been setup in the storyboard but...

There's no delegate or datasource specified for the UITableView object. The UITableViewDelegate handles cell selection. 
Once you've set up the delegate like this:

```
[self.tableview setDelegate:self];
```

You then need to implement:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"whateveryoursegueiscalled" sender:thecellyoutapped];
}
```

Have a read of Apple's tableview programming guide.

Comment: My pleasure! Definitely go read the documentation on it as there's rich functionality to get from your tableview.

Comment: That's not right, if you are using storyboard and attached a selection segue then why you have to use the code for navigation. It should work from storyboard automatically

Answer (score -2):

Chances are that you didn't add your class in the Identity inspector in your storyboard.

Select your view in the storyboard and click on identity ispector. Ensure that Class field is not empty